# I have a list and numpy array of lists. How to find the index and extract the value from index?

Tags: python

I have a list,

```py
list = ["A","B","C","D","E"]

values = np.array([[1,0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0,1]])
```

where values is of type numpy array.

I want my output to look like,

```
["A","D","E"]
["B","E"]
```

I want to loop through every element inside a list and extract the index of elements having values 1. Using the index from Values get the names for the same index from the list and store them as a list inside a DataFrame. This has to be done for every list inside values.

Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: Can you please include any code showing the attempts you have made at solving this so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a list comprehension:

```
l = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
values = ([[1,0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0,1]])
print([[x for x, y in zip(l, i) if y] for i in values])
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'E']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> from itertools import compress

>>> list_ = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
>>> values = np.array([[1,0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0,1]])

>>> result = [[*compress(list_,val)] for val in values]

>>> print(*result, sep = '\n')

['A', 'D', 'E']
['B', 'E']
```